# Snapping 3D object to 90 degree angles, but around a specific pivot?

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, 3d

Given an arbitrary pivot anywhere inside a 3D object, how can this object be snapped to multiples of 90 degrees in world space based on that pivot? I'm using Unity C#, though this may be answerable independent of the platform. Many thanks!

Comment: Note, the "RotateAround" command is incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the object you want to pivot a child of the object you want to pivot relative to, then you can reset its transform and adjust it from there.
An example is to make an arm the child of a shoulder "hinge", and the revolve it (90 degrees) around that shoulder.

This way you can make A's movement relative to C. And if you want you can move the location of C anywhere relative to B. Like for example having the hinge in the middle of B or 10 distance units above its top left corner -> Do this and A's pivot movement will still be relative to C.
[image]

Comment: I actually do have it parented at that pivot, but the problem is that I can only set either localRotation or world rotation -- localRotation will only snap around its own center, and world rotation will snap but have the position be off (because it snapped around the object's center, not the pivot center). I might misunderstand. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Philipp  - this answer is exactly correct.  Note that you rotate THE WRAPPER OBJECT.  Put a "wrapper" object around your object.  Now move your object so that the point you want on your object is at th center of the WRAPPER.  Now simply ROTATE THE WRAPPER.

Comment: Thanks for the followup!

Answer (score -1):

Take the pivot value, we'll call it p,
then take the number you want to snap to, 90 (degrees), 
then all you do in Unity is say

```
p = p - Mathf.Repeat(p, 90);
```

Basically, it says, p take away the difference between p and an aligned number close to p.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example of code using this? I'm trying to figure out where this would roughly fit in in relation to the transform rotation.

Comment: I'll take a look at your code and get back to you on that. Can you put your code in the post?